# AutoCompleteExtender with WCF service

Tags: ajax, wcf

Can some one point me to a link which shows how to use a AutoCompleteExtender with a WCF service.

Answer (score 2):

Did you try [google](http://www.google.com/search?q=autocompleteextender+wcf)?

The [first result](http://www.imaginativeuniversal.com/blog/AjaxAutoCompleteExtenderWithWCF.aspx) shows how with a simple example.